Closed expression for $\sum _{m=1}^n{{n+m}\choose n} $
I was given a problem in University:

Let $n\in \mathbb N $. Find a closed expression for the following sum $\sum _{m=1}^n{n+m\choose n}$.


I expressed binomials ${n+m}\choose {n}$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}{m!}$ and got the sum $\frac{n+1}{1}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}...$  then I took out the common factors and got $(n+1)\cdot (1+(n+2)\cdot (\frac{1}{2}+(n+3)\cdot (...$
and what then? I also tried a combinatoric approach, but failed too...
Would you give me a hint?

You ask to find the sum of $\sum_m {n+m\choose k}$ (presumably for fixed $k$?), but then seem to be looking at $\sum_m {n+m\choose m}$. Which is it?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity seems relevant.

Does this answer your question? Sum of Binomial Coefficients (same sum as yours, except that yours excludes $m=0$). Found using Approach$0$
